# Facing issues with this Game of Horses data structure. Can anyone solve this?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

[image]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<malloc.h>

char* solve (int** A ) {

}

int main() {
    int T;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    for(int t_i=0; t_i<T; t_i++)
    {
        int N;
        scanf("%d", &N);
        int i_A, j_A;
        int **A = (int **)malloc(N*sizeof(int *));
        for(i_A=0; i_A<N; i_A++)
        {
            A[i_A] = (int *)malloc(N*sizeof(int));
        }
        for(i_A=0; i_A<N; i_A++)
        {
            for(j_A=0; j_A<N; j_A++)
            {
                scanf("%d", &A[i_A][j_A]);
            }
        }

        char* out_ = solve(A);
        printf("%s", out_);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Alice and Bob are playing a game on a 
N
×
N
N×N board with horses occupying some of the cells. They play alternatively and Alice starts the game.
In a move, player selects a horse at 
(
x
,
y
)
(x,y) coordinate and moves it to either 
(
x
−
2
,
y
−
1
)
(x−2,y−1) or 
(
x
−
1
,
y
−
2
)
(x−1,y−2). The horse should remain within the bounds of the matrix after the move. The game continues till there is no possible move available. The last player to make the move wins the game.
You need to find the winner of the game.

Input
First line contains number of test cases 
T
T, then 
T
T games follow.
For each game first line contains 
N
N (dimensions of the matrix).
Then the matrix description follows. Each cell value 
A
[
i
]
[
j
]
A[i][j] of the matrix denotes the number of horses it contains.

Output 
Print "ALICE" if Alice wins the game else print "BOB".

How to solve this...?

Comment: This is a classic case for a minimax tree, implemented with recursion and backtracking.  Where are you stuck?  "Solve this problem for me" is not a Stack Overflow type of question.

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it will help:

```
int c = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (A[i][j] > 0) {
                    x = i;
                    y = j;

                    int min1 = Math.min(x/2, y);
                    int min2 = Math.min(x, y/2);

                    c += A[i][j]*(Math.max(min1, min2));
                }
            }
        }
        if (c % 2 != 0) {
            return "ALICE";
        }
        return "BOB";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
T = input()

for i in xrange(T):

    N = input()

    A = []

    for j in xrange(N):

        A.append(map(int, raw_input().split()))
HP=[]

x=0

for i in A:

    y=0
    for j in i:
        if(j>0):
            HP.append((x+1,y+1))
        y=y+1
    x=x+1
c=0

for i in HP:

    x=i[0]

    y=i[1]

    flag=0

    while True:

        if(x-2>0 and y-1>0):

            flag=1

            c=c+1 

        elif (x-1>0 and y-2>0):

            flag=1 

            c=c+1 

        if flag==1:

            break

if(c%2==0):

    print "BOB"

elif(c>0):

    print "ALICE"
```